# Loading html from local directory on WebView

Tags: android, html

I'm not able to load html file in the create in Assets directory in the project. On executing the project it says webpage not found. 
The code I have used is

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///assets/wv.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/custom_page.html");
```

This syntax works, when the custom_page.html is located in the assets directory.